# how to display an x.position in my sprite?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging, sprite-kit

i have a method to create sprites with an initial position, final position, height, image of the sprite and a name property to the sprite (to access the sprite later)
The problem is when i need to debug, because i can't display, for example, a number (of a position in this case...)
In this case, i want to know what sprite is disapearing sooner than expected, so i want to set a new parameter in my method which would be an NSString number(1,2,3..)so i could localize what sprite is making troubles... but i cant display this number or i don't know how. The other debugging technique i thought to do were to put an if(x.position> 600)callAMethod with a label, but... the coordinates are CGPoint and not float. So i'm a bit lost... Do anybody know a technique to do this??

here is my method to create sprites:

```
-(void)crearMontanaconLaPosicionFinal:(CGFloat)xFinal inicial:(CGFloat)xInicial altura:(CGFloat)altura imagen:(NSString*)imagen nombre:(NSString*)nombre
{
    CGPoint posicionFinal = CGPointMake(xFinal, altura);
    SKSpriteNode *montaña = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:imagen];
    montaña.name = nombre;
    SKAction* parallaxMoveAction3 = [SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction moveTo:posicionFinal duration:20],[SKAction customActionWithDuration:0 actionBlock:^(SKNode* montaña, CGFloat elapsedTime){
        [montaña setPosition:CGPointMake(xInicial,altura)];
    }]]];
    montaña.position = CGPointMake(xInicial, altura);
    SKAction *repetir=[SKAction repeatActionForever:parallaxMoveAction3];
    [montaña runAction:repetir];   
    [self addChild:montaña];
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to add a text element to your sprite ?  SKLabelNode ?

Comment: Yes, i would like to add that label to my sprite to display some data like x.position

Comment: SKLabelNode - https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKLabelNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I have finally found the way to solve my problem:
`-(void)didSimulatePhysics {
    [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"montaña" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
        if (node.position.x > 400)
            [node removeFromParent];
    }];`

}